# Use module.exports in vanilla javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, import, module

I am building a web application that has a browser-side application so I am using node-express to run the application and vanilla javascript for browser-side interactions.

I have another js file, that had styling `module.exports`. How do I use that in my vanilla js file? My research is pointing me to node.js solutions.

My code:

index.html:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="record">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg w-50">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rec-id" placeholder="Enter ID">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="mybtn" type="button">Enter</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center d-none" id="show-alert">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show row">
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
      <strong>Danger!</strong> Button was clicked
    </div>
  </div>

<script type="module" src="test.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```
import style from test.js
console.log(style.white);

const btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("show-alert").classList.remove("d-none")
});
```

test.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "white": "#fff",
  "black": "#000",
}
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
  },
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/express": "^4.17.17"
}
```

express.ts:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Application started and Listening on port 8000");
});

// serve your css as static
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "index.html");
});
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:1:1)


test.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at test.js:1:1
```

How do I use `test.js` in `index.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `export default` instead of `module.exports =` in test.js:

```js
export default {
  "white": "#fff",
  "black": "#000",
};
```

index.js needs to be loaded with `type="module"` and the import path for test.js should be a string.

```html
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

```js
import style from './test.js';
```